# Tried to synchronously call function {w} from a different thread - React Native Reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a problem with runOnJS in my swipe function.
All the time Im gets error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to synchronously call function {w} from a different thread.
```

Im gets the error in **panGesture** function when its called **finishAnimation**.

Code is here:

```
https://pastebin.com/YaQs4bN6
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling "finishAnimation" from the onEnd callback. That could be a problem, since finishAnimation isn't a worklet.

So you have two options:

1. **finishAnimation can be marked with the "worklet" keyword**

```
    const finishAnimation = (swipe_down) => {
        "worklet";
        // This logger can't be here anymore since it's a JS function 
        // Logger.bool(swipe_down, { swipe_down });

 
        if (swipe_down) {
            offset.value = withTiming(height.value, { duration: 100 }, () =>
                runOnJS(props.onSwipeComplete)()
            );
        } else {
            offset.value = withTiming(0, { duration: 200 });
        }
    };
```

2. **finishAnimation can be called async on the JS Thread**:

```
     runOnJS(finishAnimation)(
                e.velocityY > swipeOutVelocity || offset.value > calculateThreshold()
            );
```

Hopefully it's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Reanimated 2. you can add the `Worklet` directive to `onSwipeComplete` then you can run this function in both UI and JavaScript` threads.

More about worklet here - https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/worklets